# Using SET with calculated values in Neo4j creates a 'not defined' error

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher

I have a query based on a chess tournament. It runs fine, and returns a value. I apologize if it is ugly, and I'm aware I could clean it up. But for now it works fine, and returns the value 0.5.

To quickly give some context, the query looks at the opponents of someone's opponents, and aggregates the 2nd degree player's records', then creates a ranking.

```
MATCH (n)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(m)-[:PLAYED]-(a)-[:PLAYED]-(b)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(c)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(d)-[:PLAYED]-(e)-[:PLAYED]-(f)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(g)
WHERE n.player_id = '1'
WITH e, f,
CASE WHEN e.player_wins='1'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS wins_count
RETURN (toFloat(sum(win_count)) / toFloat(count(e))) * (sum(toInt(f.wins) ) /  (sum(toInt(f.wins)) + sum(toInt(f.losses)) +sum(toInt(f.draws)))) AS rank
```

I would like to `SET` this calculated ranking back on the player represented in node `e`. But I can't do it.

I tried this, but it didn't work...I got an error, `wins_count not defined`:

```
MATCH (n)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(m)-[:PLAYED]-(a)-[:PLAYED]-(b)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(c)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(d)-[:PLAYED]-(e)-[:PLAYED]-(f)-[:HAS_RECORD]-(g)
WHERE n.player_id = '0'
WITH e, f,
CASE WHEN e.player_wins='1'  THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS wins_count,
(toFloat(sum(wins_count)) / toFloat(count(e))) * (sum(toInt(f.wins) ) /  (sum(toInt(f.wins)) + sum(toInt(f.losses)) +sum(toInt(f.draws)))) AS rank
SET e.rank = rank
RETURN e
```

I don't know how else I can calculate `rank` without putting it after the `CASE`.

I figured since there is a problem with `wins_count` not being defined, maybe I need to carry things through, so I tried to put another `WITH` after the `CASE`, but then it failed...I somehow generated a table of ranks!!

Then, I tried to move the part that calculates the rank directly into the `SET` statement, but apparently you can't do aggregation inside a `SET` statement!!

Again, I apologize for the ugly code and realize I haven't supplied a minimal example. But I'm hoping since the problem is syntactic in nature, this will be clear to someone who knows what is wrong. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

When we declare variable in `WITH` statement we can't use it in the same `WITH` statement. For example, if we try to run the following query:

```
WITH 2 as K1, K1*3 as K2
RETURN K1, K2
```

we get an error: `Variable 'K1' not defined`.

So, we can use next query:

```
WITH 2 as K1
RETURN K1,  K1*3 as K2
```

or:

```
WITH 2 as K1
WITH K1, K1*3 as K2
RETURN K1, K2
```

and the result will be:

```
╒═══╤═══╕
│K1 │K2 │
╞═══╪═══╡
│2  │6  │
└───┴───┘
```